Data Feed for Gold (XAU/USD)
Hi I've been searching for Orderflow trading softwares & different real-time data feeds they use. For Stocks it's easy to get live orderbook data. I'm confused which data feed would be best for Gold/XAU/USD. I'll be grateful if someone helps me to figure it out.

XAU is all OTC. Best to use Bloomberg or LSEG (Refinitiv) to get broad access to different quotes.
